# Invert rotation of an object unreal engine

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

Hi i am trying to rotate an object like dota 2 demo hero and now i can rotate the object successfully but only on mousewheel up . What my problem is the mousewheel down which should rotate invertly

Here's my BP

[image]

Can someone help me please. Thank you in advance guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's alright now . I've got it :)
here's my solution

[image]

Comment: This practice is troublesome if you plan to maintain it on the long run. It'd be best if you configure Inputs and treat them as, for example, an Axis Input where you can define a range of -1 to +1 and, probably, you can then add analog sticks or other controller friendly options. Just a suggestion, but try not to consume inputs directly.